# create numbered, ordered list of section header elements from html using xPath

Tags: php, recursion, xpath, nested, header

I want to parse some HTML to create a nested navigation (ordered list for a table of contents) based on the section headings elements (H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6) using XPath. For exampe, if I have a structure like this:

```
<h2>Header 1.</h2>
<h2>Header 2.</h2>
<h3>SubHeader 2.1</h3>
<h4>SubHeader 2.1.1</h4>
<h2>Header 3.</h2>
<h3>SubHeader 3.1</h3>
<h3>SubHeader 3.2</h3>
```

I would like xPath to find all of the above header tags, or any other header tags, and parse them so I get an ordered list / menu like this:

```
Header 1.
Header 2.
  SubHeader 2.1
  SubHeader 2.1.1
Header 3.
  SubHeader 3.1
  SubHeader 3.2
```

I guess there is recursion involved to nest the elements properly. I found the following code that I tried to modify in order to extract the headings, but I just can't get my head around it:

```
$headers =<<<EOT
    <h2>Header 1.</h2>
    <h2>Header 2.</h2>
    <h3>SubHeader 2.1</h3>
    <h4>SubHeader 2.1.1</h4>
    <h2>Header 3.</h2>
    <h3>SubHeader 3.1</h3>
    <h3>SubHeader 3.2</h3>
EOT;

function extractH ($level, $xpath, $dom, $position = 0, $number='')  {
    global $headerCount;
    $prevLevel = $level-1;    
    $headings = $xpath->query("//*/h{$level}[count(preceding-sibling::h{$prevLevel})={$position}]");

    foreach ($headings as $key => $heading)   {
        $sectionNumber = ltrim($number.".".($key+1), ".");
        $headerCount--;
        echo "<li><span class='fat'>#: ".$headerCount." ".$heading->nodeValue."</span> [key= ".($key)."], [level= ".($level)."]</li>"; /* NEW */

        if ($headerCount >0) {
            $children = extractH($level+1, $xpath, $dom, $key+1, $sectionNumber); // original
        }

        if (!empty($children))    {
            $headerCount = $headerCount-1;
             echo "<li><span class='fat'>No.: ".$headerCount." ".$child->nodeValue."</span> [key= ".($childKey)."], [level= ".($level)."]</li>"; /* NEW */
        }

    }
}

$dom2 = new DomDocument();
$dom2->loadHTML($headers);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom2);
$headerCount=$xpath->evaluate("count(//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4 or self::h5 or self::h6])");
echo "headerCount: ".$headerCount;
$output = extractH(2, $xpath, $dom2);
```

If I apply the above code, I get the following (header count, key and level is for testing purposes; 
styling, i.e. , links etc., not inlcuded since the order of headers does not work yet).

```
headerCount: 7
#: 6 Header 1. [key= 0], [level= 2]
#: 5 Header 2. [key= 1], [level= 2]
#: 4 SubHeader 2.1 [key= 0], [level= 3]
#: 3 SubHeader 2.1.1 [key= 0], [level= 4]
#: 2 Header 3. [key= 2], [level= 2]
#: 1 SubHeader 3.1 [key= 0], [level= 3]
#: 0 SubHeader 2.1.1 [key= 0], [level= 4] // This should not be there
#: -1 SubHeader 3.2 [key= 1], [level= 3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply loop over the header elements and open/close `<ul>`s when appropriate:

```
$previousLevel = 0;

echo '<ul>';

foreach ($xpath->query('//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4]') as $headerElement) {
  // Grab the level number (1, 2, 3 or 4)
  $level = $headerElement->nodeName[1];
  // Add <ul> when the level increases (should only increase one by one)
  if ($level > $previousLevel && $previousLevel > -1) {
    echo '<ul>';
  }
  // Close as many levels as needed when the level decreases
  elseif ($level < $previousLevel) {
    echo str_repeat('</ul>', $previousLevel - $level);
  }
  // Display the header text in a list item
  echo '<li>', $headerElement->textContent, '</li>';
  // Store the current level for next iteration
  $previousLevel = $level;
}

// Close remaining levels
echo str_repeat('</ul>', $level ?? 0);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/vt3oR** - click the little "eye" button next to the output to see it formatted as HTML, since the markup is in one line.

Notes:

- a better approach would probably be to store your header tree in some kind of PHP structure first, then pass it over to a view to display, instead of doing it all at once,
- this is obviously over-commented for the purpose of this answer :)

Comment: That's a very clever solution. Thank you. I am just wondering how to add respective final `</ul>` closing tags - it seems that at the end there is always, at least, on closing tag missing. Not sure if it's always just one tag missing. In that case I think it would be sufficient to just add another tag at the end like this, I guess `echo '</ul></ul>';`?

Comment: Sorry @Jörg, you're right, see my edit. You have to close one `<ul>` per heading level based on the last level (or 0 if there was no headings to begin with).

Comment: I forgot to mention another thing I 'd like to include. Do you see a way to account for all the span tags that follow one heading and come before the next heading starts? I'd like to display them as list elements under the corresponding heading as well. Maybe some sort of extra loop as your script runs through the headings? I am not sure what kind of xPath query could fetch me all spans that come under the heading currently processed in the script, though. Maybe you have an idea? :)

Comment: I think putting this code within the foreach loop works for spans following any heading tags: `foreach ($xpath->query("//*/span[count(preceding-sibling::*[self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4]) = {$count}]") as $span) {
    echo '<li>', $span->textContent, '</li>';
  }` with `$count=0;` being set at the start and incremented by one within each iteration inside the loop. But I just realized that `<spans>` might, apart from following an H tag, also be nested within `<p>` or `<ul>` tags, i.e., and that above code does not work in these cases. Any idea how to account for these szenarios as well?

Comment: It's me again :) It seems that changing `preceding-sibling` to just `preceding` did the trick.